# Permanent of doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: permanent

Is there a faster ($O(a^n)$ at $a<2$ or quasiP or poly) algorithm for permanent of doubly stochastic matrix compared to an arbitrary $0/1$ permanent?

Is there at least a deterministic polynomial time approximation scheme for doubly stochastic matrices?

In other words is handling of doubly stochastic matrix permanent any easier compared to an arbitrary $0/1$ matrix permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Van der Waerden's conjecture, proved by Egorychev and Falikman, gives a lower bound on the value of the permanent of doubly stochastic matrices.

Linial,Samorodnitsky and Widgerson  (2000) use that to develop a deterministic method to approximate the permanent of doubly stochastic matrices or matrices that are close to being doubly stochastic.

Look at the paper,

Linial, Nathan; Samorodnitsky, Alex; Wigderson, Avi
A deterministic strongly polynomial algorithm for matrix scaling and approximate permanents.
Combinatorica 20 (2000), no.4, 545–568.

Available here: [https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/alex_perm.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Enati/PAPERS/alex_perm.pdf)

Comment: dont think this answers ds matrices are any easier as same method can be used to approximate any 0/1 matrix permanent.